# Why SVG Mask would work on production but not on staging?

Tags: svg, mask

I have an SVG that includes a clip-path with a mask, the code for the svg is directly in-line on the page (as opposed to being called as an img). I am having a really weird issue where on production server, the svg displays completely correctly, but on the staging server everything outside of the mask displays correctly but everything within the mask does not display at all. I've triple checked that the code is exactly the same in both environments.

When I hover over the broken masked portion in the inspector, it highlights it to show that the size is correct and it is clearly an object that is there, but none of the fills are displaying no matter what I do to any of the paths within the svg.

I'm not even sure where to start looking for answers for this, does anyone have any guidance?

it's something like this, in pseudocode:

```
<svg>
  <path></path> // works both in production and in staging
  <path></path> // works both in production and in staging
  <g clip-path="url(#clip-0)">
    <mask> //nothing within this mask tag works in staging, but it does work in production
      <rect></rect>
      <path></path>
    </mask>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-0">
      <rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is the rest of the code on the page identical between the two environments?

Comment: yes that's why it's so confusing

Comment: Have you done a diff between the two to confirm?

Comment: Why are you clipping a mask? What are you doing with the mask? What shape are you masking? Anyway: the shapes inside the mask are not visible.